# Complicated Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have Data as below

```
Value(City)    Key1              Key3                Key4
Baltimore      111111            111                 122
Towson         111111            111                 122
Columbia       111111            111                 122
SilverSpring   111111            222                 122
Burtsville     111111            222                 122
Ellicotcity    111111            222                 122
```

by creating a dictionary Currently i am grouping the above as:

```
if key1 in data_dict:
    data_dict[key1].append(value)
else:
    data_dict[Key1] = [value,]
```

and i insert data by using the below code.

```
collection.insert_many([{'key': k, 'values': v} for k,v in data_dict.items()])

Key : 111111
Values : [Baltimore, Towson, Columbia, SilverSpring, Burtsville, EllicotCity]
```

but i have to create a dictionary like this.
The first part i am able to derive with the above mentioned code.
i am not able to generate the second part having the "keys"

```
{
  Values : 
        [    "Baltimore",
             "Towson", 
             "Columbia",
             "SilverSpring",
             "Burtsville",
             "Ellicotcity"
        ]
  Keys :    [   
            {key1 : 111111},
            {Key2 : [1,1,1,2,2,2]}, #group array numbers just running numbers indicating the position
            {Key3 : [111,222]},   #Address Number unique
            {Key4 : [122]}         #Record2Pos Number unique
        ]
}
```

After research i found out we have to use nested dictionary.
I am new to Python and need help.

Comment: You need to edit your question and show us what you have already tried, add your code. As it stands, this question seems more like a request for people to write code for you, which isn't what StackOverflow is about.

Comment: It's not clear what have you tried and didn't work. Also please elaborate on your desired output.

Comment: @CentAu
Added the code to get the first part. but the second half has little complicated ones

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example done at the python prompt - a great way to experiment with code before creating a module to test concepts that you're learning.

```
>>> dict1 = {'a':0,'b':1}
>>> dict2 = {'c':2,'d':3}
>>> nestedDict = {'key0':dict1, 'key1':dict2}
>>> dict1
{'a': 0, 'b': 1}
>>> dict2
{'c': 2, 'd': 3}
>>> nestedDict
{'key1': {'c': 2, 'd': 3}, 'key0': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}}
>>> nestedDict.keys()
['key1', 'key0']
>>> nestedDict.values()
[{'c': 2, 'd': 3}, {'a': 0, 'b': 1}]
```

From here, you'll have to figure out exactly how to structure your data as required. Also, you should search for how to create a dictionary. There are many ways, well documented here on SO.

Comment: Thanks i will try.